# Importing animation function from custom swift file failed

Tags: ios, swift

I was creating animations for buttons using extension in swift but when i call the animation function it generates error.

```
import UIKit

extension UIButton{
func wiggle() {
    let wiggleAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "psoition")
    wiggleAnim.duration = 0.05
    wiggleAnim.repeatCount = 5
    wiggleAnim.autoreverses = true
    wiggleAnim.fromValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 4.0, y: self.center.y)
    wiggleAnim.toValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 4.0, y: self.center.y)
    layer.add(wiggleAnim, forKey: "position")
}
```

}

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var colorizeBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var wiggleBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dimBtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func colorizeBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
   
}
@IBAction func wiggleBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    wiggleBtn.wiggle()
 }
@IBAction func dimBtnwasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
   
}
```

}

[View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1mc4.png)

Comment: Whenever i call the wiggle func in my buttion action error occurs: value of type UIView has no member 'wiggle'

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wiggleBtn` is of type `UIView` but you write an extension to `UIButton`.

Either change the extension to `UIView` or change the type of `wiggleBtn` to `UIButton`.